# Get data from records having multiple count and manipulate them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, window-functions

I have a sample record like below in one of my SQL tables:

[image]

What I want is my select query should take the student record which has multiple count of same subjects, ie, Student A has a count(6) for subject COD and use a case statement to give the first record as failed and rest of the record as After Fail.

Ex output:

[image]

I'm not able to implement a correct logic to get this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @aRvi yea , but this is breaking my head from two days :D

Comment: show what you have tried, share db fiddle for the same

Comment: @aRvi i have tried getting the counts for different students based on the subjects but am not sure on how to categorize it in a case statement by taking the top 1 from the count and taking the rest for another

Comment: share db fiddle link with the above schema

Comment: Aside: TSQL has a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_, but there is no `case` _statement_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions. The logic is to enumerate and count the number of records having the same student and subject in a subquery, then use that information in the outer query:

```
select id, student, subject, marks,
    case 
        when cnt > 1 and rn = 1 then 'Fail' 
        when cnt > 1 and rn > 1 then 'After fail'
    end output
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by student, subject order by id) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by student, subject) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server it seems you're looking for something like this

```
with
students_cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by Student order by ID) rn
    from SomeTable),
multi_cte as (
    select *, max(case when rn>1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Student order by ID) multi
    from students_cte)
select case when multi=1 and rn=1 then 'Fail' else 
       case when multi=1 and rn>1 then 'after fail' else null end end [output]
from multi_cte
order by ID;
```